# String interpolation for keys in array?

Tags: ruby

I'm supposed to be doing this:

```
attribute_name = "key_i_want"
scores = []

candidates.each do |candidate|
    scores.push candidate.attributes.merge(:{#attribute_name} => {stuff})
end

scores
```

What I want to happen is that the category name, which in this case has the key "key_i_want", gets added to the hash, and its value will be "stuff". Is there some kind of "interpolate string" function, where I can add hash k-v pairs to an existing hash.

Another thing, what happens in this function is that I have an empty array called "scores", fill it up with the candidate+score hashes, and return the array scores at the end, is there some kind of syntactic sugar or something for this?

Comment: Why not just simply `.merge(attribute_name => stuff)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way to merge, as well as the cleaner way to create `scores`:

```
scores = candidates.map do |candidate|
  candidate.merge({attribute_name => stuff})
end
```

This uses [`Hash#merge`](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Hash%3amerge) and [`Array#map`](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Array%3amap) (assuming `candidates` is an `Array`).

Ruby has syntactic sugar that wraps method parameters in a `Hash` for you if you write them in pairs with `=>` between them. So the second line could also be this:

```
  candidate.merge(attribute_name => stuff)
```

Also, if `attribute_name` is a `String` but the rest of the keys in `candidate` are `Symbol`s, use [`String#to_sym`](http://www.rubydoc.info.nyud.net/stdlib/core/String#to_sym-instance_method) so that the resulting `Hash` will have consistent keys:

```
  candidate.merge({attribute_name_string.to_sym => stuff})
```

Answer (score 0):

> *Is there some kind of "interpolate string" function, where I can add hash k-v pairs to an existing hash.*

No need for *interpolation*.

Do this:-

```
  merge(attribute_name => stuff)
```

> *Another thing, what happens in this function is that I have an empty array called "scores", fill it up with the candidate+score hashes, and return the array scores at the end, is there some kind of syntactic sugar or something for this?*

```
attribute_name = "key_i_want"
candidates.each_with_object([]) do |candidate,scores|
    scores.push candidate.attributes.merge(attribute_name => stuff)
end
```